# How do I plot two values against each other in tableau

Tags: plot, charts, tableau-api

I have two values I wish to plot against each other in tableau. They are two totals aggregated around the same date. I can get them to the point where they are plotted on a dual access against the date like so:

[image: dual axis plot]

but any attempt to plot them against each other for correlation has come to nothing. I've tried simple conversion to scatterplot, using calculated fields, using a cross tab with subtitles and attempting to only plot the subtotals against each other all of which have failed. I could do it in Excel but have to do it in tableau.

I have consulted the official Tableau 9.0 guide, google and existing questions on Stack Overflow all to no avail. If I was doing this in BOXI, I could just select the columns and chart them. How do I do the equivalent visualisation in Tableau?

Comment: for "subtitles" pleaes read "subtotals"!!! Sorry typo.

Comment: Stack Overflow allows you to edit your question to clarify and fix typos, update with new info. That's kind of the advantage of Stack Overflow over previous forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't clear about what type of chart you want to make.

Do you want a scatter plot? If so, put one measure on the row shelf, the other measure on the column shelf, and one or more dimensions (such as your date) on the detail shelf to define how finely to aggregate the data. Check the aggregation functions you use (SUM, AVG)  and the aggregation level for your date fields (YEAR, MONTH ...) as desired. You probably want to use the *second* block of date aggregations on the menu unless you want to group all January data together regardless of year.

If you want a connected scatter plot, set the mark type from automatic to line and move the date field from the detail to the path shelf. You might also then want to put the date on size, color or legend to visually show the direction of time on the line. You might need to change that field to attribute in some cases to avoid creating multiple lines.

Tableau is fantastic once you learn how it works, and get a strong understanding of how choices about treating fields as dimensions or measures, or discrete or continuous impacts the behavior. If you skim over those details, you can still make beautiful charts by following recipes, mimicking examples (and asking StackOverflow), but Tableau's behavior will seem mysterious and arbitrary.

If you take some time to learn the fundamentals about how Tableau works, it will repay your time investment. I recommend Joshua Milligan's book Learning Tableau for a good way to start, along with the training videos on the Tableau website.

Comment: Thanks will try that. It is a scatter plot I'm after. I've spent a lot of time getting to know tableau (George Peck's "official guide" book start to finish and adhoc re-referencing and a whole heap of online tutorials but the devil is in the detail as they say!

Comment: Thanks Alex. Dragging the date dimension to details on the marks card produced a single point scatter plot. [Detailed comment to finish it out for reference for other people with same question ..... to complete the scatter plot, I then dragged the date dimension to Color on the marks card (to get individual data points) and dragged a trend line from the analytics pane showing linear correlation and voila Scatterplot of two measures, aggregated by date dimension]. Thanks for the steer.

Comment: To clarify, you don't get 'individual points' in the scatter plot because of moving the date dimension to Color or another shelf, but by setting the granularity of the date dimension in a way that partitions the data to generate more marks (such as exact date, or Month, or M/D/Y)\

Comment: Yes, sorry omitted a step in my comment there. Aggregate the data around the date dimension to the required level of granularity (week, day, month, quarter, year etc.) and drag it to "Color" on the marks card.